# Statement in jdbc retrieving only the 1st record though there are several records

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

The below code iterates, while loop, and retrieves all the records that are matched:

```
ResultSet rs3 = st.executeQuery("select id from fbprofiles where age<=(select age from fbprofiles where id="+user+") and id not in("+user+")");
        String id;
        query = "select id from fbprofiles where age<=(select age from fbprofiles where id="+user+") and id not in("+user+")";
        System.out.println(query);
        //ResultSet rs4;

        while(rs3.next())
        {
            st = con.createStatement();
            id = rs3.getString(1);
            System.out.println("id: "+id);
            /*query = "select name from fbpages where name in(select name from pagelikes_"+id+" where name not in('"+pagesLiked.toString()+"')) and category in("+category.toString()+")";
            System.out.println(query);
            rs4 = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs4.next())
            {
                message += "<a href="+rs4.getString(1)+".html style=\"color:black\">"+rs4.getString(1)+"</a><br>";
                pagesLiked.append(rs4.getString(1));
            }*/
        }
```

output:

id:2

id:3

But when I remove the comments, the loop is iterated only once, the resultset contains only 1 record instead of 2.

I have used different and sameresultsets for all the queries, which has also gave the same output with only 1 record.

All the queries are working 5n when I have checked in SQL database(11g).

Comment: can you provide a bit more of you code: Where do you declare the statement `st`, why do you use the same name for two different statements, where do you close the statement(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing rs when you execute next query on the same statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, Exception {
        Connection con = ConnectionDefinition.getOracleConnection(); //my oracle connection
        String q1 = "select object_name from user_objects";      
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareCall(q1);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery(q1);
            if(rs.isClosed()){
                System.err.println("FRIST RS IS CLOSED");
            }
        }     
        con.close();
    }
```

Comment: Yaaa....
it worked ......
I thought re-intialling a statement, statement st = con.getStatement(), might behave like a new statement, but it did not behave so. I have used few different statements, but instead, I have used all statements with different variables for each resultset, I mean to run different queries, and it worked for me. Thanks a lot ...... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute more than one `Statement` simultaneously with one `Connection`. When you execute the second query (with another `Statement`) you close the `Statement` that you're currently iterating. Get another `Connection`, use it to get your second `Statement` and then you use that `Statement` to get another `ResultSet`.

Comment: No, thats not true. You definitly can execute more than one statement per connection simultaneously!

Comment: @fritjof Do you know what a [cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29) is?

Comment: Yes, I know. Please look at the code: TO opens a new Statement-Object. If you use a single statement-Instance you cant run two queries simultaneously, but here you have two statement-instances. Thats ok!

Comment: OP only has one `st`.

Comment: Youre right. But here you have two `Statement` instances by calling `Connection#createStatement`! He reuses the variable, thats a bit weired.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Your answer says that a second Connection is required and that is not necessarily true. I just "simultaneously" (i.e., alternately, row by row) traversed two ResultSets (`rs1` and `rs2`) created by running .executeQuery on the same Statement object (`st`). Executing the second query (and creating the second ResultSet) did not close the first ResultSet. If your answer is specific to Oracle then perhaps you should mention that.

Comment: @GordThompson The [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) Javadoc says (in part) *By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly close a statment's current `ResultSet `object if an open one exists.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That quote says that a second Statement object will be required, but not a second Connection.

Comment: @Elliott .....
does it mean that the initial resultset(rs3) gets exausted when I create another statement?
I have run the following code and it worked fine for me:

while(rs.next())
{
    Statement st2 = con.createStatement();
    pagesLiked.append(rs.getString(2));
    message += "<a href="+rs.getString(2)+".html style=\"color:black\">"+rs.getString(2)+"</a><br>";
    rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select category from fbpages where name='"+rs.getString(2)+"'");
   }

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ... and, like many other things JDBC, it apparently depends to some extent on the driver implementation. My testing shows that HSQLDB does not enforce the rule you cited (not always, anyway), but Derby does.

Comment: yaaa ....
I heard that we need to use 2 separate statements instead of 1, which might cause an error like invalid operation. I don't know much about that.
That is the reason why I have tried using with different statements in my code, but it still gave the same output.

Comment: Javadoc says that you can only have one `ResultSet` per **Statement**-Instance. Again here you have **two** `Statement` instances! And of course you can have several `Statement` instances per `Connection`. That does not depend on implementation.

Comment: The [`Connection.createStatement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28%29) Javadoc also says (in part) *The holdability of the created result sets can be determined by calling [`getHoldability()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getHoldability()).* And `getHoldability()` says *the holdability, one of `ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT` or `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT`*. I think a lot of this must be implementation specific.